# GetCurrentPerson returns null

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, google-play-services

I'm tryin to add login with Google to my app. I'm following [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/google-services%5CSigninQuickstart/) example. I get the button to work and I can choose from my accounts to log in. But when I log in, I can't access GetCurrentPerson (it returns null).

Code:

```
void UpdateUI (bool isSignedIn)
    {
        if (isSignedIn) {
            var person = PlusClass.PeopleApi.GetCurrentPerson (mGoogleApiClient);
            var name = string.Empty;
            if (person != null)
                name = person.Name.ToString();
            mStatus.Text = "Signed in as " + name;

            FindViewById (Resource.Id.sign_in_button).Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
        } else {
            mStatus.Text = "Signed out";

            FindViewById (Resource.Id.sign_in_button).Enabled = true;
            FindViewById (Resource.Id.sign_in_button).Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        }
    }
```

Full code [here](http://pastebin.com/xBZP4rDX)

I registered my app to the API using the SHA-1 of the keystore etc. (I didn't use the Client ID though...)

Anyone know what I'm forgetting or doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Had similar issue and it was the app name in my case - use lower case. Also make sure that the SHA key is correct (debugging on different computers requires different keys...)

Comment: Also check on Activity result for the result code you're getting from google